# AppCompat.Platform is inaccessible due to protection level Xamarin Forms PCL

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I'm trying to use this [custom renderer](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/Renderers/ListViewRenderer.cs). And I'm getting the error.

> AppCompat.Platform is inaccessible due to protection level Xamarin Forms PCL.

The same error for `ConditionalFocusLayout`. Is that renderer meant to work with PCL?

Comment: you're not supposed to interact with components from the android platform within your pcl directly

Comment: @Dbl This is the custom renderer provided by microsoft. but I can't seem to find any other way to animate deletion in listview on android.

Comment: You could provide a github repository isolating the issue. With the information you're currently providing it is rather difficult to pinpoint where you're heading the wrong direction

Comment: I made a demo using the `ListViewRenderer`, but didn't get the error. Could you please post the related codes or detailed steps of reproducing the problem?